# How do I get rid of curved edges that bridge the two edge loops together in attached model below?

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface

I have a model of a Rook, after applying a sub div modifier and creasing a few edge loops I am left with these curved edges that form the bridges between the edge loops as shown in the image. Auto smooth is enabled. I want the curvature of the upper edge loop to continue. [image: Edge Problem]

link to model: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pOFzSxaiFRGXxxMSYnYX707fe1JY9bKK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reasons:**

1. The edge is missing a crease, so the *Subdivision Modifier* deforms it.
2. You've enabled the *On Cage* option in the modifier panel, which prevents you from noticing it.
3. Your model is too low poly, the *Subdivision modifier* doesn't know which way to curve the edges.

**Solution**

1. Add a crease to the edge, or add some loopcuts.
2. Disable the *On Cage* option - it has no benefit here, only hides real geometry.
3. Add more geometry, so you can better control the curvature.

[image]

Add more geometry.
If you only add loopcuts, you'll need to correct the shape.
It's easier to rebuild the model with more sides.

[image]

Comment: I did try the above but got straight edges instead of curved edges that continue the edge loop

Comment: Adding loop cuts does help either

Comment: @Kluivert I'm confused, I thought getting rid of curved edges was the goal :). Consider editing your question, so it's clear what is the desired result.

Comment: I am sorry, I'll edit it, what I want to accomplish is to have the curvature of the edge loop continue after applying the sub div mod instead of having that dip, that's why I used the on cage option.

Comment: Right, I get it now. The *On Cage* option won't help you there, you need to add more geometry. I'll update my answer on how to get there :).

Comment: Thanx, It worked!